# Magento 2.4 | Filters are no longer seen with Elasticsuite

Tags: magento2, attributes, layered-navigation, filter, elasticsearch

I have updated Magento to version 2.4.2 and have also activated Elasticsuite as the default search engine.

Elasticsuite installation went smoothly and the module is correctly installed. The search bar works fine but in the category page you can no longer see the Magento default filters, namely Color and Size. The price filter, on the other hand, is there but does not show prices correctly.

**Before I installed Elasticsuite:**

[image]

**After installing Elasticsuite:**

[image]

I have already run all the commands to reindex and update Magento but the problem persists.

How can I do?

Comment: which Elasticsuite module version are you using?

Comment: Hi! I use Elasticsuite 2.10.x version for Magento 2.4.2

Comment: Are you using any third party filtered navigation modules?

Comment: @paj no, i use magento layered navigation but I believe that the smile elasticsuite module overrides the layered navigation and I don't know how to disable/remove this override

Comment: I have not had any problems with Elasticsuite 2.10.3 Layered Navigation and Magento 2.4.2. Are you certain that you do not have any other layered navigation modules installed?

Comment: Now I see the color and size filters but they are only present in the sub categories. How can I show these filters in all categories with elastic suite?

Comment: Hi! I have same error

Comment: https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/issues/474

Comment: I found reason and soution.this issue came from setting

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.this is not a bug.
go to admin panel then go to

1). **Stores -> product(under attribute)**

2). now you can select any product attribute and go inside.

3). select  **Storefront Properties(in left tab)** .

4). go to **Facet coverage rate**

5). set it value to 0